# References (and a question) on the "fine" topology of powersets

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

Recently I've been trying to understand powerset topologies better, and came upon the following reference:

> **Frank Wattenberg**, *Topologies on the set of closed subsets*. Pacific J. Math. 68(2): 537-551 (1977). [[Project Euclid Link]](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-68/issue-2/Topologies-on-the-set-of-closed-subsets/pjm/1102817257.full)

There the author introduces in Definition III.3 a topology on the set $\mathrm{Cld}(X)$ of closed subsets of a topological space $X$ called the **fine topology**, which is defined as follows:

- First we take a locally finite collection of open subsets $\mathcal{U}=\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ of $X$ and an open subset $U$ of $X$, and define
  $$\langle U;\mathcal{U}\rangle\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\left\{C\in\mathrm{Cld}(X)\ \middle|\ \text{$C\subset U$ and for each $\alpha\in I$, we have $U_{\alpha}\cap C\neq\emptyset$}\right\}.$$
- Then we consider the family of all $\langle U;\mathcal{U}\rangle$ for all open $U$ and all locally finite open families $\mathcal{U}$. This forms a basis, which generates the fine topology.

Is there some place where I could read more about this topology, besides Wattenberg? (I've already tried searching for works citing Wattenberg, but they all do so for different reasons than the fine topology)

Second, does this construction also work to put a topology on all of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, instead of just on $\mathrm{Cld}(X)$?

Comment: This is the Vietoris topology. You may find some literature in the Encyclopedia of mathematics page about [hyperspace](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hyperspace) (there, a different base is described but the topology is the same).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Hi მამუკა! Could you elaborate a little bit? I think the two topologies are supposed to be distinct in general: Wattenberg says (on p. 13) that the Vietoris topology is coarser than the fine topology, and it seems they also behave somewhat differently; e.g. the Vietoris topology satisfies the "Monotone Limit Theorem" (II.8 in the paper) but the fine topology does not.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the fact that he considers locally finite families, not only finite ones! No, I have never encountered this topology, sorry.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that the method of nonstandard neighborhoods employed in the paper has a category-theoretic counterpart, that trades a topology $\tau$ on $X$ for the relation $\text{``$-$ is a $\tau$-accumulation point of $-$''}\subseteq X\times\operatorname{Filters}(X)$, viewed as a morphism $\operatorname{Filters}(X)\dashrightarrow X$ in the category of sets and relations.

Comment: Maybe you could find something about this fine topology in that context in the (huge) book "[Monoidal topology](https://www.google.ge/books/edition/Monoidal_Topology/yIj2AwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=monoidal+topology&printsec=frontcover)" by Hofmann, Seal and Tholen

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks, მამუკა! I'll try looking there :)